# ngIf inside NgFor not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I can't get this two `ng-container`-conditions inside `ion-item` get to work:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="slide.options">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let option of slide.options">
        <ng-container *ngIf="option.type === 'boolean'">
            <ion-label>
                <h2 *ngIf="option.title" [innerHTML]="option.title"></h2>
                <p *ngIf="option.description" [innerHTML]="option.description"></p>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-toggle *ngIf="option.checked !== undefined || option.disabled !== undefined" [disabled]="option.disabled" [checked]="option.checked"></ion-toggle>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="option.type === 'range'">
            <h2 *ngIf="option.title" [innerHTML]="option.title"></h2>
            <p *ngIf="option.description" [innerHTML]="option.description"></p>
            <ion-range *ngIf="option.min !== undefined || option.max !== undefined" [min]="option.min" [max]="option.max" [step]="option.steps" pin="true" snaps="true">
                <ion-label range-left>{{option.min}} {{option.unit}}</ion-label>
                <ion-label range-right>{{option.max}} {{option.unit}}</ion-label>
            </ion-range>
        </ng-container>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

They are always seen as false. This results in an empty space:

[image: Empty ion-items in ion-list]

But in this way (or when adding the same conditions directly to the `ion-toggle` and `ion-range`-elements) it was nearly working (except that the `ngIf` on `ng-container` again was always false, while the `ngIf` on `ion-label` was executing fine):

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let option of slide.options">
        <ion-label *ngIf="option.checked !== undefined || option.disabled !== undefined">
            <h2 *ngIf="option.title" [innerHTML]="option.title"></h2>
            <p *ngIf="option.description" [innerHTML]="option.description"></p>
        </ion-label>
        <ng-container *ngIf="option.min !== undefined || option.max !== undefined">
            <h2 *ngIf="option.title" [innerHTML]="option.title"></h2>
            <p *ngIf="option.description" [innerHTML]="option.description"></p>
        </ng-container>
        <ion-toggle *ngIf="option.checked !== undefined || option.disabled !== undefined" [disabled]="option.disabled" [checked]="option.checked"></ion-toggle>
        <ion-range *ngIf="option.min !== undefined || option.max !== undefined" [min]="option.min" [max]="option.max" [step]="option.steps" pin="true" snaps="true">
            <ion-label range-left>{{option.min}} {{option.unit}}</ion-label>
            <ion-label range-right>{{option.max}} {{option.unit}}</ion-label>
        </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's your problem here? seems correct, can u show console.log of your data?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @DanielSeguraPérez I added a screenshot.

Comment: @Und3rTow There's no error or relevant log entry in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by not using `ng-container` for `*ngIf` but for the iteration with `*ngFor` and putting the `*ngIf` on the `ion-item`:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="slide?.options">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let option of slide.options">

        <ion-item *ngIf="option?.type === 'boolean'">
            <ion-label>
                <h2 *ngIf="option?.title" [innerHTML]="option.title"></h2>
                <p *ngIf="option?.description" [innerHTML]="option.description"></p>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-toggle *ngIf="option?.checked !== undefined || option?.disabled !== undefined" [disabled]="option.disabled" [checked]="option.checked"></ion-toggle>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item *ngIf="option?.type === 'range'">
            <ion-label class="range-pre-label">
                <h2 *ngIf="option?.title" [innerHTML]="option.title"></h2>
                <p *ngIf="option?.description" [innerHTML]="option.description"></p>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-range *ngIf="option?.min !== undefined || option?.max !== undefined" [min]="option.min" [max]="option.max" [step]="option.steps" pin="true" snaps="true">
                <ion-label range-left>{{option.min}} {{option.unit}}</ion-label>
                <ion-label range-right>{{option.max}} {{option.unit}}</ion-label>
            </ion-range>
        </ion-item>

    </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```